# Changing and saving a label text in runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm busy writing an app for a friend, basically what it does is save a value next to each persons name then gives you an average over a period u chose. What I want to do is have each name be changeable so let's say we have Name1 Name2 Name3. When the app opens I would like to click a button open a different pabel with textboxes where u type a new name then click on update button. When this is done it will change the labels from Name1 to whatever name u typed in for example John.

I thought I would do this with something like label1.Text = textBox1.Text;

But that's not working, tried researching not much help.

If u guys have any ideas it would be appreciated.

I'm still a complete novice.

Thanks!

Comment: Some code is usefull :) "But that's not working" what is the result that you get? error?

Comment: Hey, it's working now. Below is my code but only for as long as the app is open.  Should I close the app it resets. How do I save it? Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: string name = textBox5.Text;
            label2.Text = name;

Comment: There are a lot of options for storing values when the program isn't running. You could have them simply stored in a txt file, the Windows registry, or a database, to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

So your question short is: "How to change and save he names, and have the changed names also when the application is restarted".

There are a lot of ways to save data.

1. Normal text file
2. XML file
3. Database

   //create xml file and paste the following code:
     
       
           Jhon 
           Foo 
           Dog

   ```
   private XDocument _doc;
   // path to created file.
   private string _filename = "C:\\temp\\test.xml";

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       // load file into XDocument
       _doc = XDocument.Load(_filename);

       // or loop true all the names
       var elements = _doc.XPathSelectElements("Data/Names");

       foreach (var element in elements)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(element.Value);
       }
   }

   // load name from xml into textbox when application starts
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Name[1] first child of Names, Name[2] second etc 
       XElement node = _doc.XPathSelectElement("Data/Names/Name[1]");
       textBox1.Text = node.Value;
   }

   // Create element and appeden it to Names element 
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Append node
       _doc.XPathSelectElement("Data/Names").Add(new XElement("Name", textBox1.Text));
       // Save the file
       _doc.Save(_filename);
   }
   ```